# Jenkins get/access workspace path inside pipeline stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

Below code that i have tried while running it gives error
saying no WORKSPACE variable found

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }

    stages {
        stage ("Setup"){
            steps {
                script {
                    //access workspace path to read/execute bat or exe from particular folder
                    def workspacePath = env.WORKSPACE
                     // above statement giving an error
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw. Example missing curly bracket `}`

Comment: Try just ${WORKSPACE}

Comment: Your example works.  Try with the missing curly bracket as suggested above.  Assuming you havent used `bat "cd"` or `dir()` you can also used `pwd()`